# Connect Ralink RT2571 to new PC

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers

I bought a new PC with the AsRock Z77 Extreme 4m motherboard, since this has no WLAN, I extracted the WLAN card from my old PC, a Ralink RT 2571 WF, an connected it to the new board. I downloaded the driver from http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=500 (the RT257x USB one) and installed it. In the device manager, an unknown device shows up, but if I tell it to search its driver, it does not find it (searching in the whole C partition).

The Ralink Diagnostic Test says that the WLAN Card is disabled.

I'm using Windows 7 64bit professional. Can anyone suggest me a solution to get my WLAN running?

Comment: Ralink RT2571 is NOT compatible with Win 7!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps instead of letting windows search for the driver, tell it exactly where the driver is by using the "Have Disk" method.

Example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, now it finds the driver RT73 USB Wireless LAN Card, but it cannot start it (Error 10).